# API versioning with rspec_api_documentation and apitome

Tags: api, rspec, versioning, rspec-api-documentation

We are using `rspec_api_documentation` and managed to generate the documentation for the 2 versions we have so far with the following code:

```
RspecApiDocumentation.configure do |config|
  config.docs_dir = Rails.root.join('doc', 'api', 'all')

  config.define_group :v1 do |config|
    config.filter = :v1
    config.docs_dir = Rails.root.join('doc', 'api', 'v1')
    config.api_name = 'API V1'
  end

  config.define_group :v2 do |config|
    config.filter = :v2
    config.docs_dir = Rails.root.join('doc', 'api', 'v2')
    config.api_name = 'API V2'
  end
end
```

We are using `apitome` to render these docs, however, we haven't been able to find a way to mount the routes for the 2 versions of the API 2 so far.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answering my own question in case it helps others.

1. Define your api versions as constants

   ```rb
   API_VERSIONS = [:v1, :v2]
   API_LAST_VERSION = API_VERSIONS.last
   ```
2. Define document groups for each version and output json files on separate folders

   ```rb
   # spec/spec_helper.rb

   RspecApiDocumentation.configure do |config|
     config.format = :json

     API_VERSIONS.each do |version|
       config.define_group(version) do |config|
         config.filter = version
         config.docs_dir = Rails.root.join('doc', 'api', version.to_s)
       end
     end
   end
   ```
3. Use the document groups when coding your specs

   ```rb
   # spec/acceptance/v1/users_spec.rb

   resource 'User' do
     post '/users' do
       example 'Identify a user', document: :v1 do
         # your v1 spec here
       end
     end
   end

   # spec/acceptance/v2/users_spec.rb

   resource 'User' do
     post '/users' do
       example 'Identify a user', document: :v2 do
         # your v2 spec here
       end
     end
   end
   ```
4. Comment out `doc_path` and `mount_at` from `config/initializers/apitome.rb`
5. Define a route constraint which sets them

   ```rb
   # lib/apitome_version.rb

   class ApitomeVersion
     def initialize(version)
       @path = "doc/api/#{ version }"
     end

     def matches?(request)
       # Load doc files from the right version folder
       Apitome.configuration.doc_path = @path
       # Mount all routes on the current request path (including simulated responses)
       Apitome.configuration.mount_at = request.path
       # Return a match
       true
     end
   end
   ```
6. Mount your routes using that constraint, you can optionally set a default version

   ```rb
   # config/routes.rb

   Rails.application.routes.draw do
     # Mount documentation for each API version
     API_VERSIONS.each do |version|
       mount Apitome::Engine => "/api/docs/#{ version }",
         as: "apitome-#{ version }",
         constraints: ApitomeVersion.new(version)
     end

     # Optionally default to the last API version
     mount Apitome::Engine => '/api/docs',
       constraints: ApitomeVersion.new(API_LAST_VERSION)
   end
   ```
7. Regenerate your documentation

   ```
   rake docs:generate
   ```
8. Restart your server

Comment: While this is functional it'd be great if I didn't have to override `doc_path` and `mount_at` on a constraint so please let me know if you find a better way of achieving this.